# cycle on grep function

Tags: bash, unix

I have a list of entries (specifically names) stored in a file. Just as an example, the file contains the following names:

> ```
> ACOT7   
> ATP6V0D1    
> INSIG2    
> KLHL21    
> .......
> .......
> ```

In total there are 1600 names.

I need to extract the data associated with each specific name from a file derived from an analysis previously performed. What I usually do is (for example referring to the first name):

> grep -w  "ACOT7" output_analysis.txt > ACOT7.txt

So, I extract the values of ACOT7 name from the file output_analysis.txt  and I store the data in the file ACOT7.txt. Since I have 1600 names, I can not type the string as above for 1600 names.

Can anyone help me please to find a quick way to do this type of work for all the 1600 names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for n in $(cat input.txt); do 
    grep -w "$n" output_analysis.txt > "$n.txt"
done
```